# Sending a half yearly reminder on SharePoint 2010 foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, alert

My customer using SharePoint 2010 foundation and it is not able to use "Information management policy settings".

Is there any alternatives to setup workflows sending reminders as documents/pages are not modified in certain period, for example, 6 months?

I doubt that pausing multiple workflows for 6 months is not a good idea because it will consume server resources as workflow will nonstop for 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create a custom timer jobs and implement your logic...which run every night and check the document date, which one is true for 6 months then send the email.

here are few good refrences for creating timer jobs.

http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/a-complete-guide-to-writing-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-2010/

http://www.andrewconnell.com/Creating-Custom-SharePoint-Timer-Jobs

Comment: Based on your question, I feel a timer job is the best way to go.  Long lasting workflows will give you headaches in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible for you to use [DateDiff function within a calculated column](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/043b7601-6707-4030-ac01-82b44d6fcf3a/calculating-date-time-difference?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) to find out the dates for workflows. Of course, workflows will take of the rest!

Comment: Does this calculated column is updated continuously based on changed [Today]?

Comment: No, calculated columns are only calculated upon saving.  They are static thereafter unless edited.  The calculation will then calculate once again after saving.